# Ошибка при формировании запроса, MS ACCESS C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, интерполяция

Программно формирую запрос к базе данных `Microsoft Access`, однако получаю следующую ошибку:

> **System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException:** "Отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров."

Хотя в запросе я передал значения для всех полей.

Вот код:

```
string x = textBox3.Text;
string y = textBox4.Text;
string query = "INSERT INTO translater_ (id , eng , rus) VALUES (4 , x , y)";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

По задумке есть 2 `textBox`'а: в первый я ввожу английское слово, во второй - его перевод, потом они должны добавляться как новые строки в БД. Но по нажатию на кнопкy выдает вот эту ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простите, что отвечаю так поздно, только сейчас докопался до сего вопроса)

---

Начать хотелось бы с того, что когда вопрос касается `баз данных`, то стоит указывать структуру таблицы, с которой Вы испытываете затруднения, чтобы можно было детальнее углубиться в суть проблемы

---

Я вижу Вашу проблему в том, что Вы неправильно используете [интерполяцию строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).
Взглянем на строчку:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO translater_ (id , eng , rus) VALUES (4 , x , y)";
```

Логично, что Вы хотели подставить значения переменных `x` и `y`, объявленных ранее, в строку. Делается это немного иначе:

```
int a = 2;
string interpolatedString = $"a == {a}";
Console.WriteLine(interpolatedString); // a == 2
```

Что же тут происходит? Почитаем [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

> Специальный знак `$` идентифицирует строковый литерал как интерполированную строку. Интерполированная строка — это строковый литерал, который может содержать интерполированные выражения. При разрешении интерполированной строки в результирующую элементы с интерполированными выражениями заменяются строковыми представлениями результатов выражений. Эта возможность доступна в `C# 6.0` и более поздних версиях.

Внутри интерполированной строки символы `{` и `}` становятся служебными, так как выражения, записанные внутри них, будут вычислены, а их значения будут подставлены в строку, так что если Вы захотите записать данные символы в *чистом* виде, Вам необходимо будет их экранировать:

- Так: `{{` и `}}`
- Или так: `\{` и `\}`

---

Собственно, интерполяция строк с помощью специального знака `$` является [синтаксическим сахаром](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80), добавленным в [C# 6.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6) для упрощения взаимодействия со [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting), так что последующие две записи логически эквивалентны:

```
int a = 2;
string interpolatedString = $"{{a}} == {a}";
Console.WriteLine(interpolatedString); // {a} == 2
```

И

```
int a = 2;
string formatedString = string.Format("{{a}} == {0}", a);
Console.WriteLine(formatedString ); // {a} == 2
```

---

Касательно Вашей проблемы, выражение стоит записать так:

```
string query = $"INSERT INTO translater_ (id, eng, rus) VALUES (4, '{x}', '{y}')";
```

Тогда значения `x` и `y` будут подставлены в строку, как Вы того и ожидали!

---

**Дополнение:**

Поле `id` в таблицах принято создавать в качестве [AUTO INCREMENT поля](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp), тем самым его значение будет *уникальным* для каждой записи, а также его *не придется* явно подставлять в [INSERT-запросы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)): значение будет автоматически выставлено как `предыдущее + 1`

Тогда Ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
string query = $"INSERT INTO translater_ (eng, rus) VALUES ('{x}', '{y}')";
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам Огромное!!!

Comment: @SeeSharp да не за что ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

```
$ "INSERT INTO translater_ ( eng, rus) VALUES ({x}, {y})";
```

Comment: Sql injection...